# creating datafram with 5000 row using the 500 rows reference file

Tags: r, static, stat

my reference file has 500 rows and 11 columns (years: 2007:2017) with date in those column as value.

i have to creat a dummy dataframe of 5000 rows and 11 column (years: 2007:2017). i want to put the  radom date within one month from a reference file. i think following function would creat a random date within a month.

reviewdate$x2007_1 <- as.Date(reviewdate$X2007, format = "%d/%m/%Y") + sample((-15:15), 1)

i need to creat a for loop so i can run selected column in my datafram so i can creat random date for 2007 to 2017 period.

my second question is about my reference file has only 500 records for each year and want to creat 5000 records for each year? how can i generate radom date for 5000 rows for each year using reference file which 500 rows for each year?

Comment: For the second question: You have 500 dates and want to get 5000, hence for every date you need to create 10 random dates. Just do `+ sort(sample((-15:15), 10))` instead of `+ sample((-15:15), 1)`.

Comment: thanks for your prompt response,  how can i save this (sort(sample((-15:15), 10)) ) to new dataframe